# Spring validator - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

My friend helped me up set my first spring/hibernate project and now I am trying to implement a custom validator. I already have a RegistrationForm model that uses anotations to validate. However, now I need to implement a password validator - to check if the password and confirmPassword are equal.

Problem: when I POST, if the passwords match, the data is saved. If they dont match, then at the validators following line, I get the error from the title.

```
errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "valid.passwordConfDiff");
```

The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Tutorial I followed:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-password-example/

This is what I have:

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
//@SessionAttributes(value = {"registerForm"})
@ComponentScan("ba.codecentric.movienight")
public class FrontController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired  
    @Qualifier("passwordValidator")
    private PasswordValidator validator;

    @InitBinder("password")
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.setValidator(validator);
        }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initIndex(Model model){       
        model.addAttribute("registerForm", new RegisterForm());

        Password password = new Password();
        model.addAttribute("password", password);

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registerForm") RegisterForm registerForm,
               BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @Validated Password password){

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("error", true);
            model.addAttribute("userIsRegistering", "<script>$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show();</script>");
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            return "index";
        }

        User user = new User();

        user.setUserName(registerForm.getUserName());
        user.setPassword(registerForm.getPassword());       

        userService.addNewUser(user);

        return "index";
    }       
}
```

Password validator:

```
     public class PasswordValidator implements Validator{


    public boolean supports(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return Password.class.equals(paramClass);   
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        Password password = (Password) obj;

        if (!password.getPassword().equals(password.getConfirmPassword())) {
                errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "valid.passwordConfDiff");        
        }

    }
}
```

RegistrationForm:

```
public class RegisterForm {
            @NotBlank
            @NotEmpty 
            private String userName;
            @NotBlank
            @NotEmpty 
            @Size(min=7,max=16,message="Password range error")
            private String password;

            @NotBlank
            @NotEmpty
            private String confirmPassword;
        //getters setters
        }
```

Registration form jsp:

```
 <form:form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" commandName="registerForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" method="post">

                            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"  />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="userName" class="col-md-3 control-label">User Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <form:input type="text" path="userName" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <form:errors path="userName" element="div" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" />

                            <div class="form-group">                            
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <form:password path="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <form:errors path="password" element="div" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <form:password path="confirmPassword" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                                                

                            <form:errors path="confirmPassword" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Button -->                                        
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                    <form:button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Sign Up</form:button>                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>                                                                           

                        </form:form>
```

Comment: show the syntax of what you are posting since it is complaining about the syntax

Comment: I did, and some code. Also I found out that if I put *BindingResult result* after *@ Validated Password password*, it wont throw that error, but only if I put in a user name - if there is no user name, same error occurs. I am too tired to try this, but I have an idea - instead of PasswordValidator, should I have a RegisterForm validator, and the add new user would have *@ Valid @ Validated @ ModelAttribute("registerForm") RegisterForm registerForm* instead of @ Validated Password password

Comment: (had to seperate @ annotations)

Comment: @user wrap an annotation with the ` char for annotations in comments `@AnAnnotation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Model model,
        BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    return "success";
}
```

When the object student has invalid attribute(s), then this code gives the error: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

However, if the order of arguments student and model is changed, then this method works as expected.
E.g.,

`public String processForm(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result)`

and

`public String processForm( @Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, Model model)`

both work as expected.

Please, let me know what is the science behind this.

Comment: [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods)

22.3.3 Defining @RequestMapping handler methods /
Supported method argument types

...
Errors / BindingResult validation results for a preceding command or form object (the immediately preceding method argument) 

"The Errors or **BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound immediately** as the method signature might have more than one model object and Spring will create a separate BindingResult instance for each of them "

Examples in the docs.